# Save a file with a dynamic name C#

Tags: c#, save

I'm working on a project and i need to save inputBox.Text in a text file. I know how to do this.
But i need to save it with user entered value.

I have a textBox called "Name" and a date.
I want save my file as "Name-Date".
Can someone help me?

Comment: What type of files is this ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? what have you tried/researched?

Comment: Use a writer and pass it´s name by providing `Name + Date.ToString()` or something similar, according to which format you need the date to be present within your file.

Comment: File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(textBoxName.Text, DateTime.Today.ToString()), inputBox.Text) ?

Comment: I need to write my TextBox in a .txt file.
The user need to write his name, write in a textbox and click continue. Then, my program need to save value in a .txt file, called "Name-Date".
How can i change the date for use it as a file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] lines = { textBox2.ToString(), textBox3.ToString() }; 
File.WriteAllLines(string.Format(@"C:\resultats\{0}-{1:dd:MM.yyyy}.txt", textBox1.ID, DateTime.Now), lines);
```

Comment: Thank you but I have an error "The format of the given path is not supported."

Comment: I've done this: '            string[] lines = { textBox2.ToString(), textBox3.ToString() };

            File.WriteAllLines(string.Format(@"resultats\{0}-{1:dd:MM.yyyy}.txt", textBox1.ToString(), DateTime.Now), lines);'

And i still have the same error, he wants to save me as "  date "System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text: 07/04/2015 09:32:41" string
"

Comment: @FlorianSL try textBox1.ID instead of textBox1.ToString()

Comment: I have found how to change this.
"            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            File.WriteAllLines(string.Format(@"resultats\{0}-{1:dd:MM.yyyy}.txt", nom, date), lines);
"

thanks for your help bro !

Edit : And it's not TextBox2.ToString(), but TextBox2.Text

Comment: @FlorianSL - if you format the date beforehand, you don't need to specify the format again, so `string.Format(@"resultats\{0}-{1}.txt", nom, date)` should suffice. I think the problem is the colon between `dd` and `MM` I guess that should've been `{1:dd.MM.yyyy}`, but `yyyy-MM-dd` is a better date format anyway (ISO 8601 plus automatic sorting). So `string.Format(@"resultats\{0}-{1:yyyy-MM-dd}.txt", TextBox2.Text, DateTime.Now` should also work.

Comment: Oh yea i forgot to delete it.
Ok, i'll try thank you

Answer (score 0):

*here **txtdate.Text** will get the system date (or) use your date*

**txtdate.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();**

*here **txtname.Text** is your input textname*
*we use string **namedate** for join **"Name-Date"*** 
string namedate = txtname.Text + " - " + txtdate.Text;

**using this sql query can store in db**
string sql = "insert into table_name (namedate)values('" + namedate + "')";